# How to get the process user name by PID on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, shell

I used `getpid()` to know the process PID, and now how can I get the process user name?

I tried this shell command, `ps -o user= PIDNUM`, but on Mac 10.4, it doesn't work for me.

Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 6):

`ps -ef | grep <process_pid>` --- this will give you all the information you need.

Comment: You can use awk on top of it to filter out one column.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use [**`ps`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ps.1.html) and [**`awk`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/awk.1.html):

```
% ps aux | awk -v PID=13521 '$2 == PID { print $1 }'
root
```

...where `13521` is the PID in question. Substitute for your own PID or `${environment_variable}` to taste!

If you don't have the PID, you can find all users running Google Chrome (for example) like:

```
% ps aux | awk -v app='Google Chrome' '$0 ~ app { print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 5):

the following would do it: `ps -efj | grep PID`

where

- e: selects all processes
- f: does full format listing
- j: job control format.

[http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps][1]